# TeXstudio Is Not Responding

Tags: errors, texstudio

I have been using TeXstudio for some time now, and have highly enjoyed using. However, just now it has been acting up. Whenever I open the program, my cursor always reverts to the wait-cursor, this one [image] 
, and it is rather annoying. Not only is this an issue, but I TeXstudio won't compile any of my documents.

Has anyone ever dealt with this issue?

EDIT: Here is the code that is apparently giving me trouble:

```
% Regular polygons
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

% Radius of regular polygons
\newdimen\R
\R=0.8cm

\begin{tikzpicture}

    % Indicate the boundary of the regular polygons
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-3\R]

        \draw (0:\R) \foreach \x in {60,120,...,359} {
                -- (\x:\R)
            }-- cycle (90:\R) node[above] {Hexagon} ;

        % 360/7 = 51.4286 For PGF v < 1.18 we have to round to the nearest
        % integer. Newer version support fractional angle values.
        % For a more accurate result use the sequence
        % {51, 103, 154, 206, 257, 309}
        %
       \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    % Indicate the boundary of the regular polygons
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-3\R]
        \draw (-0.8,0) -- (0.8,0); 
        \draw (0,-0.7) -- (0,0.7);
        \draw (0,-0.7) --
        \draw (0:\R) \foreach \x in {60,120,...,359} {
                -- (\x:\R)
            }-- cycle (90:\R) node[above] {Hexagon} ;

        % 360/7 = 51.4286 For PGF v < 1.18 we have to round to the nearest
        % integer. Newer version support fractional angle values.
        % For a more accurate result use the sequence
        % {51, 103, 154, 206, 257, 309}
        %
       \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This may sound stupid, but did you try turning it off and on again? The complete pc.

Comment: Uninstall, clean registry and reinstall could be a start. Could you tell us when and how it started or what you did before you noticed the issue?

Comment: @azetina I believe it began when I was practicing making drawing with the  tikz package, and I actually used an example from the tikz website. For some reason, TeXstudio automatically saved the file as texstudio_s13480.tex Did I perhaps overwrite some important file?

Comment: So, if the restart does solve your problem (temporarily, which i think it would) and you try to compile again, does it again go into nonrespondence? Maybe your document, that you try to compile is missing a `;` which causes LaTeX/TikZ to search for that (sometimes quite longish)... And i don't think, you deleted an important file.

Comment: Restarting the computer did not work.

Comment: @Mack Go with [Command Line Prompt to zero-in on Editor Specific Issues](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/open-a-command-prompt-window) and for eg: type `pdflatex your-problematic-file.tex` and observe the `errors` and wait for sometime incase you are using `xelatex` engine first time. If the problem persits, post the `problematic-file.tex` with a short [MWE code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: @texenthusiast I couldn't get that to work, so I posted my code.

Comment: `Cannot parse this coordinate \R` <- The parameter you defined doesn't work this way.

Comment: Really? I copy and pasted most of the code from [here](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/regular-polygons/), but mad only a few modifications.

Comment: Just noticed, it's not it, it's something else. One moment

Comment: In the second half of your example, there is `\draw (0,-0.7) --` and nothing more. This causes the failure.

Comment: Oh, so there should be a semi-colon there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Breaking down your example leads to path which is never finished.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\newdimen\R
\R=0.8cm
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-3\R]
        \draw (-0.8,0) -- (0.8,0); 
        \draw (0,-0.7) -- (0,0.7);
%        \draw (0,-0.7) -- % here is the problem
        \draw (0:\R) \foreach \x in {60,120,...,359} {
                -- (\x:\R)
            }-- cycle (90:\R) node[above] {Hexagon} ;
       \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Basically, the erronous lines wants to draw a line from corrdinate `(0,-0.7)` to (`--`) well, and then there is nothing, but a new `\draw command`. So the path was never finished, causing trouble.